# How to stop nginx? It keep killing one process and opening a new one with a different pid

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, systemd

I have nginx installed via the ubuntu package manager. I try and run `sudo nginx` and get

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

ok fine. run

```
sudo netstat -plant | grep 8
tcp     0    0 0.0.0.0:80    0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN    3593/nginx -g daemo
tcp6    0    0 :::80         :::*          LISTEN    3594/nginx -g daemo
```

so it seems that nginx is still running.

```
sudo nginx -s stop
```

I try and stop it, and then re-check.

```
sudo netstat -plant | grep 8

tcp     0    0 0.0.0.0:80    0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN    3736/nginx -g daemo
tcp6    0    0 :::80         :::*          LISTEN    3736/nginx -g daemo
```

so basically it just changed the pid number. Every time it does this instead of killing it. I guess it kills that process and opens a new one.

How can I actually stop it?

Answer (score -1):

I had to use the service daemon. So `service nginx stop` instead of `nginx -s stop`.

Apparently  the service daemon is the one who controls nginx, and you are just calling it when you use the -s flag. I needed to access it directly in this case

Comment: There is no such thing as a "service daemon".`service` is a command to control your  [initsystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) in this case [System V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V).